# Sharepoint change rich-text to plain text in table?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-list

I'm trying to change the formatting of a table from rich text to plain text. When i go into the options for a particular column in the table and select "plain text" from the radio buttons I get a message saying all the records will lose their formatting. which is what i want. But whats happening is that some, not all, rows will still have formatting html tags around them. For example, `<em>SomeText</em>`. I don't want these tags. I thought switching to plain text would remove the tags.

[image]

Comment: If you are satisfied with this answer, please consider marking it as the accepted answer so there are fewer questions left marked as unanswered.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've gone through with the change of the column data type from a rich text field to a plain text field, you can use the helper method `ConvertSimpleHtmlToText` found in the `SPHttpUtility` classin the `Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities` namespace.

[MSDN documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.utilities.sphttputility.convertsimplehtmltotext(v=office.12).aspx).

---

**Example usage with C# and a simple list**

```
using(SPSite site = new SPSite("your site URL"))
{
    using(SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
    {
        //Get the list with the column you want to convert
        SPList list = web.Lists[ListName];

        //Get all the list items in the list
        SPListItemCollection itemCollection = list.Items;

        //Loop through the collection of items and set
        //the field value to the converted value
        foreach (SPListItem item in itemCollection)
        {
            //Get the value of the field
            fieldValue = item[YourFieldName];

            //Set the value of your field to the converted value
            item[YourFieldName] = SPHttpUtility.ConvertSimpleHtmlToText(fieldValue, fieldValue.Length);
        }
    }
}
```